# What is the meaning of the phrase "brain of size of Wisconsin"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I was watching Breaking Bad. In the Pilot episode Hank Schrader says this to Walter White :

> "You got a brain the size of Wisconsin, but we're not gonna hold that against you."

What is the meaning of this sentence? Why did he compare his brain to a state in the US?

Comment: Sounds like he's saying that Walter has a large brain.

Comment: They live in New Mexico, which is much bigger than Wisconsin.

Comment: It's not a common idiom.  I suspect you must infer the meaning from the context.

Comment: Yeah. That's exactly what I mean

Comment: As far as size is concerned, he should have used either Texas or Rhode Island. Wisconsin is neither large nor small.

Comment: @Centaurus It's still bigger than the average brain. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To say someone has a brain the size of a state (other than the notably small states, such as Rhode Island or Delaware) is to suggest that they are smart, and even overly smart.

The speaker is a working class sort of fellow who prides himself on his common man ways. The person he is addressing is a very nerdy science teacher.

He is in effect saying

> You are an egghead and we are regular people, but we will tolerate you anyway.

Comment: I would disagree that the particular state has any relevance on its own. The comparison of a brain to any state, or any municipality, is of course hyperbole. If anything, selecting a small state suggests modesty (e.g. *we say Maryland, but mean Montana*). Only if you are making multiple comparisons does any ranking take hold: *He's got a brain the size of Cook County, and his wife's got one the size of all Illinois*.

Comment: @choster i do not suggest that the particular state name has any significance. If *any* state name were used, it would signify something large. I make reference to RI and DE only because comparison to a state that most AmE speakers would consider *small* would undermine the hyperbole.